# The data pointed to by a pointer gets corrupted just after the start of the next iteration of a for loop in copying a list at the end of another list

Tags: c, pointers, for-loop, doubly-linked-list

I am writing a code of a function `void joinList(List *l1, List *l2)` that copies a doubly linked list pointed to by `l1` into the end of a doubly linked list pointed to by `l2`, changing the list pointed to by `l2`, and keeps the list pointed to by `l1` unchanged. If `l1` points to `5, 9, 14` and `l2` points to `2, 7`, then after calling the function on both lists `l2` must point to `2, 7, 5, 9, 14` while `l1` still points to `5, 9, 14`.

Each node in either list is a structure that has 3 members: a union to represent different element data types, a `prev` and a `next` pointer.

The list itself is a structure that has 4 members : a `head` pointer that points to the first node, a `current` pointer that points to the node preceding the last inserted or deleted node, a `curPos` to keep the index of the node pointed to by `current` and a `size` to store the size of the list.

The implementation of the list works perfectly in insertion, deletion, traversal, destruction and the others.

```
typedef union type {
    int intElement;
    double doubleElement;
    char charElement;
} listEntry;

typedef struct node {
    listEntry element;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} listNode;

typedef struct list {
    listNode *head;
    listNode *current;
    int size;
    int curPos;
} List;

void initializeList(List *);
void joinList(List *, List *);
```

And about the definition of the function

```
void joinList(List *l1, List *l2) {
    listNode *slider = l1->head;
    listNode *nodePtr = malloc(sizeof(listNode));

    for (int s = 0; s < l1->size; s++) {
        printf("l2->current->next %lf\n", l2->current->next->element.doubleElement);
        *nodePtr = *(slider);

        if (!l2->size) {
            //for empty l2
            nodePtr->next = l2->current;
            l2->head = nodePtr;
            nodePtr->prev = l2->current;
            l2->current = nodePtr;
        } else
        if (l2->size == 1) {
            //for one-node l2
            nodePtr->next = NULL;
            nodePtr->prev = l2->current;
            l2->current->next = nodePtr;
        } else {
            //general case
            nodePtr->next = NULL;
            nodePtr->prev = l2->current->next;
            l2->current->next->next = nodePtr;
            l2->current = l2->current->next;
        }

        l2->size++;
        slider = slider->next;
        printf("l2->current->next %lf\n", l2->current->next->element.doubleElement);
    }       
}
```

In calling the function with 2 lists.
The last line in the loop prints that `l2->current->next` points to the proper data that I want, but just after starting the next iteration of the loop the data pointed to by this pointer gets corrupted as indicated by the `printf` statement in the start of the loop. Noting that the pointer still holds the same address in both cases. Is it possible that a loop changes data just by iteration?

Comment: @Ahmed Hesham: Is there a reason you want to copy the nodes? Why don't you go to the tail of l1, and make it point to the head of l2 (and add the two sizes together) and then be done?

Comment: @Gerhardh Finding the tail of l1 is obtained by a pointer 'current' in it.

Comment: @Spoonless This means that l1 will be a part of l2, and the user will not notice that it is like a container that is inside another container, he will think that l1 and the extended l2 are separate lists. But will that be logical ?

Comment: Perhaps you should make clear how you want the code to behave after the joining. If the l1 is added to the end of l2. (You should also add a comment that this is the desired behaviour) And then l1 gets changed, do you want the change to reflect in l2 as well?

Comment: @Spoonless What do you mean by reflecting the change in l2 please? l2 has to be changed after appending  while l1 is the same as it was.

Comment: Forget my comments about `l1` and `l2`. I mixed them both. But for copying the members you still need to do more allocation than only for 1 node.

Comment: Could you please add sample input lists and desired output list(s)?

Comment: @Gerhardh I allocated a memory space for a node only once, and each time I take a node from l1 and store it into this allocated space. I can notice some error in allocating memory here, but tell me more about your thought about this please.

Comment: You are talking about copying the list. This means for each node you must allocate memory for a copy. Otherwise you only join the list. Or something totally different.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes, If l1 has 5, 9, 14 and l2 has 2, 7 then after calling the function on both lists l2 must has 2, 7, 5, 9, 14 while l1 still has 5, 9, 14.

Comment: Please provide some visual representation of your desired result. How would the `prev` pointer of entry 5 manage to fit for 2 lists at the same time? You could add an element to `l1` and also the links within `l2` gets updated (but not the `size`). This looks like a complete mess.

Comment: ok lets say l1 has nodes with elements of values 1,2, and 3. *I'm making up notation here - bear with me* So L1==>(1,2,3) and L2==>(4,5,6) if we join them then L2==>(4,5,6,1,2,3) right? If after joining we change L1 so L1==>(1,2,834) what is the value of the elements in L2? Either L2 is unchanged (L2==>4,5,6,1,2,3)) of L2 reflects the update to L1 (L2==>(4,5,6,1,2,834)). Which one do you want?

Comment: @Gerhardh Every node in `l1` has a `next` and a `prev` pointers that are used to link the nodes of `l1` together, and every node in `l2` has a `next` and `prev` pointers that link its nodes. About updating `l1` during copying to `l2`, I want the function to take `l1` after it has completed and append it into `l2`, whenever an element is added to `l1`, you must call the function again to append the whole list not only the added node.

Comment: @Spoonless: Yes, I want the function to append the nodes of `l1` that are found currently, and if any change happens to `l1`, `l2` will not reflect that, it will be the same, like the way you copy a file on a PC.

Comment: Then you need to make a new set of nodes. One for each node in List 1. These nodes will have the same data, as List 1, but becauase they are new nodes they will have different addresses. And they will each have their own address. So you cant just malloc one node and use it for all of them because you are overwriting it each time.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, creating a new node each time is logic that is sometimes forgotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-using the same `listNode` structure for each element appended to the destination list. You must allocate a new element for each element you copy. Furthermore, there is no reason to special case `l2->size == 1`.

```
void joinList(List *l1, List *l2) {
    listNode *nodePtr;
    listNode *slider = l1->head;

    for (int s = 0; s < l1->size; s++) {
        nodePtr = malloc(sizeof(listNode));
        if (nodePtr == NULL) {
            printf("memory allocation failure\n");
            return;
        }
        *nodePtr = *slider;
        nodePtr->next = NULL;
        nodePtr->prev = NULL;

        if (!l2->size) {
            //for empty l2
            l2->head = nodePtr;
            l2->current = nodePtr;
        } else {
            //general case
            nodePtr->prev = l2->current;
            l2->current->next = nodePtr;
            l2->current = nodePtr;
        }
        l2->size++;
        slider = slider->next;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is the issue I forgot. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Your modification for my code is correct. But for anybody who pastes the code anywhere,  the `printf` statement   `printf("l2->current->next %lf\n", l2->current->next->element.doubleElement);` creates an error because if `l2` is empty, l2->current = NULL, so `l2->current->next` produces and error.

Comment: @AhmedHesham: I removed the debugging code that was indeed creating problems